# Rails 5: Nested params not nested with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a form in Rails 5.2 for a model with a `has_many :through` relationship to another model. The form needs to include nested attributes for the other model. However, the params are not nesting properly. I've created the following minimal example.

Here are my models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :component_orders, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :components, through: :component_orders

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :components
end

class Component < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :component_orders, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :orders, through: :component_orders
end

class ComponentOrder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :component
  belongs_to :order
end
```

The `Component` and `Order` models each have one attribute: `:name`.

Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_with model: @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= fields_for :components do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :name %>
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I fill out the form, I get the following params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ztA1D9MBp1IRPsiZnnSAIl2sEYjFeincKxivoq0/pUO+ptlcfi6VG+ibBnSREqGq3VzckyRfkQtkCTDqvnTDjg==", "order"=>{"name"=>"Hello"}, "components"=>{"name"=>"World"}, "commit"=>"Create Order", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"create"}
```

Specifically, note that instead of a param like this:

```
{
  "order" => {
    "name" => "Hello", 
    "components_attributes" => {
      "0" => {"name" => "World"}
    }
  }
}
```

There are separate keys for "order" and "components" at the same level. How can I cause these attributes to nest properly? Thank you!

EDIT: Here is my controller code:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
      render json: @order, status: :created
    else
      render :head, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, components_attributes: [:name])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you update the question with `orders_controller`? Also did you try changing `<%= fields_for :components do |builder| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :components do |builder| %>` as i pointed in my answer?

Comment: Adding the `f.fields_for` fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :components` in the `Order` model.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :component_orders, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
  has_many :components, through: :component_orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :components
end
```

And change

```
<%= fields_for :components do |builder| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :components do |builder| %>
```

to get the desired `params`. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :components` creates a method namely `components_attributes`

More Info [*here*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Whoops! I copied my classes wrong. I already did that and it didn't help.

Comment: @DanaScheider Ok, please update the question with `orders_controller` code

Comment: I updated it! But it seems like the controller code shouldn't affect the structure of the params.

Comment: You were right about the f.fields_for though. That did it.